# A carriage return string length can be equal to zero?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if a string that contains only a carriage return can have its length = 0.

What are the lengths of \r, \n, and \r\n ?

I think in my app i have detected such as cases but i'm not sure.
I have to make sure i'm writting correct conditions when trying to detect empty strings and those with carriage return in them.

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trimming your strings somewhere before checking the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lengths are 1, 1 & 2 as can easily be demonstrated.

```js
console.log(`\n`.length);
console.log(`\r`.length);
console.log(`\r\n`.length);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are checking carriage return lengths and not the strings representing them ? Btw , how i can copy paste a carriage return in clipboard just for testing ?

Comment: @Bardelman `\n` is *one* character. Only the string literal contains two (a backslash and an "n"). Escape sequences are a convenience of writing a specific singular character. Although *some* characters are multi-byte - higher level unicode characters, for example. EOL characters don't fall in that category.